# Using a list as an index for another list python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to create an online shopping cart system in python to understand list better but have come across some struggles.

I am having difficulties with displaying information using a list. I have already created a list where the person writes in the product the code into an empty list as shown below.

```
else:
    code_input.append(i)
    quan_input.append(s)
code_inputed.append(code_input)
quan_inputed.append(quan_input)
```

I want to use the list with the product codes to find the correlating name and price by using trying to use the code_input list as an index to find the items in the other list.

I have written the simple code to try to find if it works but it comes up with TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

The code

```
def display():
    index = code_inputed
    for i in code_inputed: # and index in range(len(productList)):
        print(index)
        print(productList[index], quan_inputed[index])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm sorry if none of this makes any sense I am only new.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you want, but do you perhaps mean:

```
def display():
index = code_inputed
for i in code_inputed: # and index in range(len(productList)):
    print(i) #CHANGED TO i!
    print(productList[i], quan_inputed[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering quickly. I changed it and it comes up with TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.     This is when I do :                        
        product = productList[I]               
        price = priceList[i]
        print(price).                                                                                                                                         But otherwise for one input works great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate this code based on your needs. But you get the idea on how to do that. I made list of dicts using 3 lists you provided (productList, priceList, code_of_product) And everything else is just straight forward :)

```
productList = ["Salad Server Set", "Party Serviette Holder", "Tea Set", "Mixing Bowl Set", "Knife Block Set",
           "Coffee Capsule Holder", "Plastic Sensor Soap Pump", "Storage Bucket", "Oven Glove", "Apron", 
           "Biscuit Barrel", "Chopping Board", "Carioca Cups", "Soup Bowls", "Elevate Wood Turner", 
           "Pasta Machine", "Teapot", "Cake Pop Scoop", "Cookbook Stand", "Chocolate Station", "Coffee Maker", 
           "Pepper Mill", "Salt Mill", "Glass Storage Jar", "Measuring jug", "Kitchen Scale", "Tenderiser", 
           "Pizza Docker", "Knife Sharpener", "Steel Cork Opener", "Steel Garlic Press", "Steel Can Opener", 
           "Stainless Steel Crank Flour Sifter", "Mineral Stone Mortar and Pestle", "Citrus Cather", 
           "Cherry & Olive Pitter", "Multi Grater-Detachable", "Stainless Steel Colander", "Steel Pizza Pan", 
           "Pop Container"]

priceList = [18.70, 11.95, 39.95, 49.95, 99.95, 29.95, 79.95, 24.95, 9.95, 29.95, 39.95, 12.95, 54.95,
             43.00, 19.95, 144.95, 29.95, 9.95, 29.95, 34.95, 29.00, 84.94, 84.95, 4.95, 19.95, 39.95, 34.95, 
             19.95, 79.95, 36.95, 34.95, 36.95, 33.95, 74.95, 19.95, 27.95, 26.95, 44.95, 12.95, 22.95]; 

code_of_product = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
       38,39]

# Generate a list of dicts from 3 lists productList, priceList, code_of_product
products = [ {'product_name': productList[i], 'price': priceList[i], 'code': code_of_product[i] } for i in range(len(productList)) ]


def catalogue():
    global productList, priceList, code_of_product
    print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format("code", "product", "Price $"))
    print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format("----", "------------------------------------", "-------"))


    for prod in range(len(products)):
        print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format(products[prod]["code"], products[prod]["product_name"], products[prod]["price"]))

catalogue()
        

            
code = int(input("Please input code?"))
quantity = int(input("Please input quntity?"))



def showRecord(cd, qty):
price = products[cd]["price"]

total = float(price)*float(qty)
print(f"Product name: {products[cd]['product_name']}")
print(f"Price: ${price}")
print(f"Total: {total}")

showRecord(code, quantity)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it all works great. Except how do I do multiple inputs instead of just the one?

Comment: You're welcome!
Can you give me more details about your question? :D
Do you think about constantly looping "Please input code?, please input quantity?"

Comment: Yes sorry, the person constantly types in their code and quantity until they type END. Once END is written it will display all of the data in the order of code. If the person has not put in the code during the loop function then 0 will be shown in the quantity, price section.

Comment: Sorry, i used internxt to store the screenshot of what I need to be.  The link if you want to see it is https://drive.internxt.com/sh/folder/5e298e1c9f7da9a1a06a/5f307e53fc1d5ea0eaa31c36fb928f2643eafc6b460c3968c16d138d4091275f